# Grep and the % percentage symbol

Tags: regex, bash, grep

When using grep on the command line I am getting different results when I use a `%` percent symbol.

I expect this expression to match it returns nothing:

```
bash-4.1$ echo ' (in=Gen)' | grep -in '*(*)'
```

However if I include a leading percentage character it's a match:

```
bash-4.1$ echo ' (in=Gen)' | grep -in '%*(*)'
1: (in=Gen)
```

Is the percent `%` symbol a special or control character in grep? Looking at the available documentation I don't see any reference to it.

Comment: `*` on its own means nothing - it's a quantifier. It means 0 or more of token that comes before it.

Comment: replace `%` with anything you like you will get same result.

Comment: You are mixing `glob` and `regex`. By default, `grep` will use regexes, in which case `*` is interpreted as a quantifier (0 or more). On the other hand, other tools like `bash`, `ls`, .... use globs, where `*` is interpreted as `0 or more of any character`. The equivalent for regex is `.*` (`.`: any character in regex, `*`: 0 or more times).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put any other (valid) character, there would be a match too e.g. using `,`:

```
% echo ' (in=Gen)' | grep -in ',*(*)'
1: (in=Gen)
```

The problem is with your pattern, `*(*)`, here:

- `*` means to match zero or more of the preceding token, as there is no preceding token it matches `*` literally. As there is no `*` present, the pattern does not match anything

While in `%*(*)`:

- `%*` means to match `%` zero or more times, as there is no `%` present, `grep` matches nothing for `%*`; in this case `grep` only matches the last `)`

Comment: Nitpick: it doesn't match any blanks. `grep` uses unanchored search by default, and in the second example it matches just the parentheses and their content.

Comment: This answer is wrong. The quantifier `*` stops being a quantifier if there is nothing to quantify. It becomes a literal `*` in Basic Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 1):

In BRE (Basic regular expressions) that `grep` uses (as opposed to ERE, extended REs from `egrep` or `grep -E`, if a `*` is nor a quantifier of a preceding expression, it will match the literal star. (This also happens with a `^` that is not at the beginning of an expression, and a `$` that is not in a position to match end of line: They are interpreted as the normal characters `^` and `$`.

From `man 7 regex`:

> '^' is an ordinary character except at the beginning of the RE or(!) the beginning of a  parenthesized  subexpression,  '$'  is  an ordinary character except at the end of the RE or(!)
>          the end of a parenthesized subexpression, and '*' is an ordinary  character  if  it  appears at the beginning of the RE or the beginning of a
>          parenthesized subexpression (after a possible leading '^').

As to your second example, what is only matched is the closing bracket (marked with a `^` on top):

```
              ^
echo ' (in=Gen)' | grep --color -in '%*(*)' 
1: (in=Gen)
```

Notice the use of `--color` to `grep` to highlight what actually is matched, this has been pretty invaluable to understand grep's behavior).

The seach you are looking for, is likely this one:

```
% echo '*(in=Gen)' | grep -in --color '*(.*)'
1:*(in=Gen)
```